# How to validate a request body is a valid JSON coming into a python flask application

Tags: python, json, http, flask

I have a simple python flask app

```
1 @app.route("/endpoint/", methods=['POST'])
2 def mypostmethod():
3
4    if 'Content-Type' in request.headers and request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
5        if request.is_json:
6            req_data = request.get_json()
7            try:
8                test_json = json.loads(req_data)
9                return req_data
10           except ValueError as e:
11               return Response('invalid json', status='400')
12        else:
13            return Response('response is not json', status='400')
14
15
16       if 'content' not in req_data:
17           return Response("No content received in request", status='400')
18
19       content = req_data['content']
20       return content
```

and I curl as follows:

I was wondering how do I put some code to make sure we validate **line 6** so that it is a valid json?

If for e.g. the following was passed in, it should be OK

> '{"content": "Blah"}'

But if the following was, then it should return 400 ERROR with a custom response msg

> '{'content': 'Blah'}'

I tried a few past/old posts but can't make it work? Any ideas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to test it below or you could check out [flask-validate-json](https://github.com/machine-w/flask-validate-json) but it looks like you can resolve this with the [request object methods](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/flask/flask-get-request-parameters-get-post-and-json/#request-json). Also, a 401 response means unauthorized it seems a 400 response is more appropriate? [HTTP status responses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

When you load the json into the json module it will check if it is valid and raise ValueError if it is not.

You can use [flash](https://junxiandoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/flask/flask_message_flashing.html) to provide the user feedback and it will be available in your error template. You may want to look into [custom error handling](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/errorpages/?highlight=error%20handling).

```
# Standard library implementation

# See if request is in fact json
if request.is_json:
    data = request.get_json()
    try:
        # Check if it is valid by loading it into json module
        test_json = json.loads(data)
        return data
    except ValueError as e:
        # Return invalid json
        flash('invalid json')
        return render_template('error.html'), 400
else:
    # only accepts json data
    flash('data is not json')
    return render_template('error.html'), 400


# error.html
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
   {% if messages %}
      {% for message in messages %}
         {{ message }}
      {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested... please check my updated question, but it does not return what I want? I wanted it to not abort

Comment: You have to try to load the json into the json module since it will check if it is valid. I updated my answer after viewing the flask documentation. You can change the aborts to whatever you need to.

Comment: In your example you never loaded it into the json module. import json test_json = json.loads(req_data)

Comment: I like your answer, only 1 problem. If I do as you say (updated my question again) It says line-16 and line-17 is unreachable. Also, can't seem to get it to print my custom error response. I get the generic "Bad Request 400"

Comment: see updated answer -- using custom error template. I would look into using a custom error handler if you need that type of functionality.

Comment: If this information has answered your question please accept answer. I have modified it for you to provide error 400 with custom response message.